# MS Word 2007 - How to set up placeholder text to mimic text but not formatting

Tags: ms-word, word-template, word-field, word-contentcontrol

I'm probably biting off more than I can chew with this particular problem, but I'll try to be as specific as possible in case it's within my scope.  Disclaimer:  I'm not terribly experienced with MS Word, beyond simple data entry/some formatting, and I have absolutely zero experience working with macros or VBasic.  Unfortunately, I'm afraid the solution to my problem will come in the form of one of those last two.

THE GOAL:

What I want to do is to have placeholder text throughout my template document that will change content but not formatting when the first instance of it is changed.  Basically, I'm writing a template for support manuals for a software suite.  Each app has certain similar features like the menu bar, data entry screen, diagnostic log screen, transaction history, etc., so I am pre-writing those sections and using placeholders when I need to insert certain app specific properties.

I started off using the Insert->Quick Parts->Document Property->Subject tool which I used as a placeholder for the app name.  I set the Property to [Subject] and then used Insert->Quick Parts->Field->Subject throughout the document, wherever I needed to include the app name.  This worked fine in this case because the app name will always be capitalized.  I simply change the text in the first [Subject] (which is content controlled) and update the fields throughout the document, and they all match nicely, easy-peasy, work done, go home and drink beer, right?

Not quite.

Our software handles part tracking via scanners and SQL Server, so while the interface and menu in the apps remains largely unchanged, the parts they track change from app to app.  Because of this, I need to change the part name when I reference it within the text of the manuals; for example, if I'm working in ToiletPap.app and our TP is tracked by the roll, I need every mention of [Component] to be changed to roll.  If I'm working in LightBulbs.app, I need [Component] to say bulb.

My first efforts went toward creating a custom doc property called Component using the Advanced tab under the Document Properties dropmenu.  I then created a plaintext content control around my first [Component] titled Component and made my next [Component] a field with modified code: {COMPONENT * MERGEFORMAT}.  This comes from copying what I can find when [Subject] works.  This didn't work at all; updating the text in the first CC doesn't change the Content doc prop, and my fields return "!Undefined Bookmark, COMPONENT".

I got close to what I need by using the [Comments] doc property, set initially to [Component].  I used it just like [Subject], but (this is when I realized that capitalization was going to be an issue) when I mention my [component] in-text, as often as not, I need to to be lowercase instead of upper.

I've looked on MS's forums and a few others as well as here on SO, and I can't find anyone who's trying to do the same thing, much less an answer to how.  Please keep in mind when answering, it would be a great help to me if you would include step-by-step instructions on how to enter/implement the code you provide because, as I mentioned, I have no idea how to go about editing macros/VBasic for MS Word.

To restate and summarize my overall question:  How can I use a placeholder that displays the text "[Component]" so that, when I change the first instance of [Component] to something else, say "hopper", every subsequent instance of [Component] is updated to hopper but maintains its current capitalization and formatting scheme?

Apologies for the length of the request, but I wanted to make sure I explained the situation as accurately as possible.  Thanks in advance for your consideration and responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this one after a couple extra hours of tinkering.  I didn't need macros or VBasic, either.

On the first instance of [component] I created a plain-text content control to act as a container (not a necessity, but it makes it look nicer.  Will likely cause a problem eventually, but for now, it's working as intended) and bookmarked it.  Then, for all other instances of [container] I selected each and used Insert->Quick Parts->Field->Ref with the following field code:

```
REF Text1 \*Lower
```

Where "Text1" is my bookmark and "*Lower" indicates all lower case.  The *Lower can be replaced with *Upper or *FirstCap to indicate all upper case or capitalize the first letter respectively.  Now, each field reflects the text of the first with the capitalization appropriate to each field's location within the document.  Just like using the doc prop with [Subject], ^a -> f9 is needed to update all fields within the document.